# Radio Button acts as a check box

Tags: android

Hello I'm working on android app, and I have several radio button on my app and when I click the radio button it can do what I want which is show a web page, but when I click another radio button it acts as a check box. Here is my code :

```
RadioButton webss = (RadioButton) findViewById (R.id.studentsite);
    RadioButton webst = (RadioButton) findViewById (R.id.staffsite);
    RadioButton webbaak = (RadioButton) findViewById (R.id.baak);
webss.setOnClickListener(new RadioButton.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
            {
            callintent(v);
            }
    });

    webst.setOnClickListener(new RadioButton.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
            {
            callintent(v);
            }
    });

    webbaak.setOnClickListener(new RadioButton.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick (View v)
            {
            callintent(v);
            }
    });
public void callintent(View view) 
{
    Intent intent = null;
    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.studentsite:
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("http://studentsite.gunadarma.ac.id"));
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.staffsite:
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("http://staffsite.gunadarma.ac.id"));
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.baak:
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("http://baak.gunadarma.ac.id"));
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
default:
            break;
    }
```

do you have any to fix those code? Thanks.

Comment: yes I always mark every one answer if it really works with my code :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put all of your RadioButtons in your layout file inside a `RadioGroup`
This way whenever one is checked, the others are automatically unchecked.

Comment: Whoala!! Thank you, I've missed that important part.

Comment: You should accept this answer and some of your previous ones to get your rate up <:

Answer (score 0):

You need to add those radiobuttons inside  tag in the xml file.
Like this.
    `<RadioGroup>
        <RadioButton/>
        <RadioButton/>
    </RadioGroup>`

Answer (score 0):

Use RadioGroup. [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/)  is a good example.